# Open a new tab if it is not already open

Tags: javascript

```
$('#cptagswrap').click(function() {
    window.open('tags.php');
});
```

This opens a new browser tab and load `tags.php`.

I need firstly to check it `tags.php` is somewhere already open.

- If yes, then go to the tab without opening a new one.
- If no, then open it.

Something like:

```
if (tags.php).is(':open') {goto tags.php;}
else {window.open('tags.php');}
```

Any help?

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) is your best buddy.

Comment: @Amy, documentation says - `If the name doesn't exist, then a new window is opened` but it is not true. New tab is open anyway.

Comment: Please create a reproducible example in your question where using unique names doesn't work.

Comment: @puerto it's true, you're doing something else incorrectly, but I can't guess what without seeing a [mcve]

Comment: @Amy, what is true? That browser will not open a new tab if it is already open?

Comment: @puerto You quoted the documentation and said it wasn't true.  You are incorrect.  the documentation is correct.  You are doing something incorrectly, but i can't guess what without a [mcve]

Comment: @Amy, you need an example for click to open a file? Click anywhere on web and you'll see - new tab is open twice if you clicked twice.

Comment: @puerto Show us what you tried.  I'm not going to show you an example.  Please provide a [mcve] of your attempt.  And no, I've done this before.  *You* are doing something wrong.  The documentation is fine.

Comment: @Amy neither you nor I should write any example. My question is perfectyly clear without any example.

Comment: @puerto Okay, I guess it works correctly for everyone but you then.  I can't say for sure, because *I can't see what you tried to identify what you did wrong.*  But if you don't want help, that's fine.  Good luck to you.

Comment: @puerto perhaps you didn't notice that the code in your question isn't making use of the `windowName` argument.

Comment: @puerto Now, if you still think MDN is wrong about `windowName`, then show us a [mcve] demonstrating that it is wrong.  The burden of proof showing it doesn't work is on you, not us.  If you want help, show us a MCVE demonstrating that the `windowName` argument doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from documentation that @Amy says:

```
var windowObjectReference = null; // global variable

function openFFPromotionPopup() {
  if(windowObjectReference == null || windowObjectReference.closed)
  /* if the pointer to the window object in memory does not exist
     or if such pointer exists but the window was closed */

  {
    windowObjectReference = window.open("http://www.spreadfirefox.com/",
   "PromoteFirefoxWindowName", "resizable,scrollbars,status");
    /* then create it. The new window will be created and
       will be brought on top of any other window. */
  }
  else
  {
    windowObjectReference.focus();
    /* else the window reference must exist and the window
       is not closed; therefore, we can bring it back on top of any other
       window with the focus() method. There would be no need to re-create
       the window or to reload the referenced resource. */
  };
}
```

Comment: and how can I implement this in my `click` function ?

Comment: You only have to declare a global variable outside click function and adapt the code, is so easy, try it and tell me :D